# Why does Languagetool with ngrams in Textstudio not work?

Tags: texstudio

Actually I use Languagetool 4.2 and TexStudio 2.12.10 and it works perfectly.

Now, I'd like to add ngrams and I used for that, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354716/languagetool-with-n-grams-in-texstudio-in-windows/446849#446849) information.

[image]
In `Languagetool.jar`, `ngrams` works, but not in TexStudio.

Could you explain what I made wrong?

Regards Mario.

Comment: Well, where's your ngrams file? Is it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\TeXstudio`? Also, what's in the cfg file, please clarify. What language are you using it for?

Comment: Hi Troy, thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong `.jar` file.
Instead of `languagetool-server.jar` try `languagetool.jar`

As per the usage help of `languagetool-server.jar` it requires additional arguments that the other `.jar` files do not:

```
$ java -jar languagetool-server.jar
> Usage: HTTPSServer --config propertyFile [--port|-p port] [--public]
> ...
```